# Switching OutSequence in WSO2 ESB Proxy Service based oh SOAP response

Tags: proxy, sequence, switching, mediator, wso2-esb

I deployed a proxy service in WSO2 ESB for dataset retrieving from a SOAP WS, and i have an OutSequence based on a sequence calling a template.

I have to channel various WS response based on the different request routing them on different files written by the vfs transport.

Actual sequence is the following:

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="seq_prova_con_template">
   <call-template target="file">
      <with-param name="filename" value="IstatAllDataflow-template.xml"></with-param>
   </call-template>
</sequence>
```

I think about a switch-case mediator but i'd like to understand how "catch" the information for choosing the right case. In the example:

```
`<switch source="//m0:getQuote/m0:request/m0:symbol"     xmlns:m0="http://services.samples/xsd">
      <case regex="IBM">
           <!-- the property mediator sets a local property on the *current*     message -->
          <property name="symbol" value="Great stock - IBM"/>
      </case>
      <case regex="MSFT">
          <property name="symbol" value="Are you sure? - MSFT"/>
      </case>
      <default>
          <!-- it is possible to assign the result of an XPath or JSON Path     expression as well -->
      <property name="symbol"
            expression="fn:concat('Normal Stock - ', //m0:getQuote/m0:request/m0:symbol)"
            xmlns:m0="http://services.samples/xsd"/>
  </default>
```

`

i ask myself how to set the source param of the switch case, and i'd like to know if someone has already implemented a solution like this in order to use a single proxy service for differentiate various answer from the WS.
My sequence is the following:

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="seq_template_switch">
   <switch xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:m0="http://services.samples" source="??????">
      <case regex="QueryStructure">
         <call-template target="file">
            <with-param name="filename" value="IstatAllDataflow-template.xml"></with-param>
         </call-template>
      </case>
      <case regex="GetCompactData">
         <call-template target="file">
            <with-param name="filename" value="GetCompactData-template.xml"></with-param>
         </call-template>
      </case>
   </switch>
</sequence>
```

I need to catch the choice for the switch case from che method inside the request of my request message, in order to write a certain file when i ask for a kind of answer, and another file with a different name when i ask for another kind of answer.

[EDIT] Log file has this:

```
TID: [0] [ESB] [2015-09-18 10:33:09,125]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  To: http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous, WSAction: , SOAPAction: , MessageID: urn:uuid:7cc540d3-2893-4b0e-8a24-ab4538236d45, Direction: response, Envelope: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soap:Body><QueryStructureResponse xmlns="http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/sri/service/2.0"><QueryStructureResult><RegistryInterface xmlns="http://www.SDMX.org/resources/SDMXML/schemas/v2_0/message"><Header><ID>IT1001</ID><Test>true</Test><Name xml:lang="en">ISTAT_JD_237</Name><Prepared>2001-03-11T15:30:47+01:00</Prepared><Sender id="ISTAT"><Name xml:lang="en">Italian Statistical Institute</Name><Contact>
```

It would be useful making the choice of switch/case mediator about the tag `<QueryStructureResponse>`. Instead of this tag i could have`<GetCompactData>` , for example. I'd like to create a switch/case mediator that is driven by the presence of one of this two tags. This would be a good beginning for understanding how to use XPath location and using a single sequence for differentiating SOAP answers in different file by vfs transport.The choice of the file to write in would be taken by the kind of answer from the WS.

Comment: You want to call different sequences based on content in your SOAP response. please correct me if my understanding is wrong. Please provide  your SOAP response as well to answer your question.

Comment: I think it's more useful basing it on content in my SOAP request: i could put this sequence in a scheduled task or using a request with a proxy service, and i'd like to convoy the answer according to the request. I don't know what to put in the source of the switch sequence if i want to chooose the destination according to some keywords in the request message. I hope i've been clear, thank you so much.

Comment: you need to use Xpath in source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below should work for you. It is checking if QueryStructureResponse exists in SOAP xml or not. If available then it will call **IstatAllDataflow-template.xml** template otherwise it will invoke **GetCompactData-template.xml** template.

```
<switch source="boolean($body//*[local-name() = 'QueryStructureResponse'])">
        <case regex="true">
           <call-template target="file">
        <with-param name="filename" value="IstatAllDataflow-template.xml"></with-param>
     </call-template>
        </case>
        <case regex="false">
           <call-template target="file">
        <with-param name="filename" value="GetCompactData-template.xml"></with-param>
     </call-template>
        </case>
     </switch>
```

Another solution using filter in WSO2 esb.

```
<filter source="boolean($body//*[local-name() = 'QueryStructureResponse'])" regex="true">
   <then>
      <log>
         <property name="======================== TRUE =========================" value="true"/>
      </log>
      <call-template target="file">
         <with-param name="filename" value="IstatAllDataflow-template.xml"/>
      </call-template>
   </then>
   <else>
      <log>
         <property name="==================== FALSE =========================" value="false"/>
      </log>
      <call-template target="file">
         <with-param name="filename" value="GetCompactData-template.xml"/>
      </call-template>
   </else>
</filter>
```

Comment: Thank you, now I have to choose the exact path for catching my source from che request XML message passing through the proxy service (using a scheduled task or a simple SOAP UI message... is it possible?). Ideas about where i can find the source of the message in order to exactly drive the switch? I could know how to navigate inside the message with Xpath, but i don't know how to refer my Xpath to the request message... I hope i rightly explained my problem.

Comment: Can you provide your XML and keyword based on you want to invoke sequence.

Comment: I've tried with source="$body/*", but it doesn't work. I have enabled synapse.xpath.dom.failover.enabled=true
in the conf file.

Comment: Please put a log mediator and try to print $body and provide that XML.

Comment: Sorry, But I can not find SOAP response. You have provided sequence.

Comment: Now there is the soap answer. Thx.

Comment: Provided XML is not valid and incomplete.

Comment: I only put the starting part of the response because i thought it was enough for defining the XPath for take-over the kind of response (QueryStructureResponse or GetCompactData). The answer is very long (350 kb), if it is useful I could put the final part

Comment: Edited my answer..please modify it according to your requirement.

Comment: Really thank you, your solution is good. My final aim is to apply this switch case not only in a boolean decision, but looking for the ID of a dataset, and every dataset with an ID will be written in a different file. So i need a switch case with more cases than two. However your solution is very useful. Now i will see how to enrich the number of cases.

Comment: What about if I want to manage more than two only response (not only QueryStructureResponde and GetCompactData)? Here we have a boolean true or false, it will be useful having a function with a larger matching. I would avoid nested switches, obviously.

Comment: I will suggest to go for Filter instead of switch case.

Comment: I think it's still an inadequate solution for my final issue. Switch and filter mediator are just a little step for it, and I thank you for helping me, it's been precious. Now i will work for extracting the dataset name from the ws response for personalize destination file. For example, if i get a certain dataset called "my_dataset_01", i have to set it in a file named "my_dataset_01.xml". I have to extract the name of the dataset in order to define how to rename the file in vfs transport. I think i will open a new question for this, do you agree?